# AutoCompleteTextView list covered by keyboard

Tags: android

I have the same problem as with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994051/keyboard-covers-the-last-item-of-an-autocompletetextview). I attempted the answer in the comment but still no luck.

**Here is my code:**

Layout:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content" 
/>
```

Java code:

```
    String[] values = {
                "abc_0", "abc_00", "abc_000",
                "abc_1", "abc_11", "abc_111",
                "abc_2", "abc_22", "abc_222",
                "abc_3", "abc_33", "abc_333",
        };

    final AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.test);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, values);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Upon typing "abc", it will display the suggestion list as expected. But on the last 2 items `abc_33` and `abc_333`, they are blocked by the soft `keyboard`.

Is there any suggestion on how to have the list not to be covered by keyboard?

Comment: Add ScrollView to the main layout so that you can scroll up.

Comment: ScrollView is the ugly way. Like suggested in the other thread, use the android:windowSoftInputMode parameter to achieve the correct behavior. What Theme do you have set on your Activity?

Comment: Yes I agree with DroidBender. I applied 1 theme to my Application. It uses `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the AutoCompleteTextView into RelativeLayout parrent